How to connect nRF Mesh with OOB Security adding In fliutter?
    V/MeshManagerApi(17303): Provisioning pdu sent: 0x030005
    V/MeshManagerApi(17303): Received provisioning message: 0x03010100020003000000080008
    V/ProvisioningCapabilities(17303): Number of elements: 1
    V/ProvisioningCapabilities(17303): Public key information available: false
    V/ProvisioningCapabilities(17303): Static OOB information available: : false
    V/ProvisioningCapabilities(17303): Output OOB size: 0
    V/ProvisioningCapabilities(17303): Input OOB size: 8
    V/InputOOBAction(17303): Input oob action type value: Input Alpha Numeric
    D/fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh.DoozMeshProvisioningStatusCallbacks(17303): onProvisioningStateChanged 0503f008-d1d8-25c8-4a59-494f542d3235
    D/fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh.DoozMeshProvisioningStatusCallbacks(17303): meshNodeAlreadySaved true
    D/fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh.DoozMeshManagerCallbacks(17303): onNetworkUpdated
    I/flutter (17303): [NordicNrfMesh] successfully assigned 2 to node !
    E/MethodChannel#fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh/mesh_manager_api/methods(17303): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported algorithm!
    E/MethodChannel#fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh/mesh_manager_api/methods(17303): at no.nordicsemi.android.mesh.MeshProvisioningHandler.sendProvisioningStart(MeshProvisioningHandler.java:378)
    E/MethodChannel#fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh/mesh_manager_api/methods(17303): at fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh.DoozMeshManagerApi.onMethodCall(DoozMeshManagerApi.kt:455)
    E/MethodChannel#fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh/mesh_manager_api/methods(17303): at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
    E/MethodChannel#fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh/mesh_manager_api/methods(17303): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
    E/MethodChannel#fr.dooz.nordic_nrf_mesh/mesh_manager_api/methods(17303): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
    E/flutter (17303): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Unsupported algorithm!, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported algorithm!
    E/flutter (17303): at no.nordicsemi.android.mesh.utils.AlgorithmType.getSupportedAlgorithmValue(AlgorithmType.java:91)
    E/flutter (17303): at no.nordicsemi.android.mesh.provisionerstates.ProvisioningStartState.createProvisioningStartPDU(ProvisioningStartState.java:117)
    E/flutter (17303): at no.nordicsemi.android.mesh.provisionerstates.ProvisioningStartState.executeSend(ProvisioningStartState.java:101)
    E/flutter (17303): at no.nordicsemi.android.mesh.MeshProvisioningHandler.sendProvisioningStart(MeshProvisioningHandler.java:378)
    E/flutter (17303): at no.nordicsemi.android.mesh.MeshProvisioningHandler.startProvisioningNoOOB(MeshProvisioningHandler.java:306) 


please clarify what you've tried and what issue you're facing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
